# Integrate elastic load balancer with autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services

Im studying about elastic load balancer and autoscaling and I have a doubt.

For example, I create a autoscaling group, this autoscaling group will just start if I create a cloud watch alarm with some conditions right?

Its not supossed to create an autoscaling group and start an instance and add this instance to the scaling group right? The idea of autoscaling it is just to start new instances when needed?

And then it is possible to use this two services together (elb and autoscaling), but Im not understanding how it works.

For example I create an autoscaling group, then I create an ELB and I add some instances to this ELB.

But how the autoscaling with ELB works then? For example if my ELB have a lot of requests and I need more instances, how this is works with autoscaling? We need to create a cloudwatch alarm for ELB to start an autoscaling group when the requests in ELB are > than something? But how the autoscaling group then is associated with ELB? Maybe the question it is a bit confused, but also a bit confuse about this two concepts, if you dont understand something please say.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An autoscaling group is tied to a *launch configuration* and zero or more *scaling policies*. It's also tied to zero or more *load balancers*. This is the "magic" that causes instances to appear inside the ELB without further intervention.

The *scaling policies* are referenced in the *alarms*- common actionable alarms are CPU load, host count, latency, or [ELB surge queue length](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/10/28/elastic-load-balancing-adds-new-cloudwatch-metrics/).

Finally, a *launch configuration* contains information used to launch an EC2 instance (AMI, ssh key name, IAM instance profile, security groups).